# How do I iterate over an attribute to check for equality?

Tags: rust

I often find myself wanting to have an iterator over an attribute of a certain struct or tuple, so I would like to know how would one do that properly.

I currently have two slices of type `$[(usize, &str)]` and I want to check if their respective indices (the `usize`) are equal,
such that `tuple1.0 == tuple2.0` in every iteration of the slices.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi. Your question is rather cryptic to me. Could you add an example of those slices and show us what do you want to check?

Comment: How do you define "best"? Do you want the most compact code, the fastest or the most memory efficient? Or some other criterion?

Comment: @Jmb best as in, most readable and simple. And perhaps with pointers towars performance improvements and downfalls of the approach.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze in the end I want to loop through both and compare the usize element against each other.

Comment: @GuillemVidalSerrats I don't understand the "compare the usize element against each other" part. Could you please show an example of slices when this comparison is true, and an example where it is false?

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze it's a tuple composed of two elements `(usize, &str)`. I have two slices composed of such tuples, and I want to compare them, such that tuple1.0 == tuple2.0 in every iteration of the slices.

Comment: @GuillemVidalSerrats Can you not just use [`Iterator::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.eq)? `slice_a.iter().eq(slice_b.iter())`

Comment: That would compare the entire slices (so the iterator is not useful in the first place), they want to compare just the first member. So maybe something along the lines of `std::iter::zip(slice1, slice2).all(|((idx1, _), (idx2, _))| idx1 == idx2)` instead. Although might need a pre-check that the slices are the same length.

Comment: @Masklinn looks good! I still cannot iterate over an attribute, is that not possible?

Comment: Ah, if we're just checking the first element then we can do `slice_a.iter().map(|x| x.0).eq(slice_b.iter().map(|x| x.0))`. [`Iterator::eq_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.eq_by) could also be used once it is stabilized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterators have an `eq()` method that checks whether two iterators yield exactly the same items. You can use this to compare if the "indices" in two slices are the same:

```
fn indices_match(a: &[(usize, &str)], b: &[(usize, &str)]) -> bool {
    a.iter().map(|&(i, _)| i).eq(b.iter().map(|&(i, _)| i))
}
```

This implicitly checks that the slices have equal length.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to compare the two slices as a whole or if you want to focus on each pair of matching elements.

In both cases you have to iterate on both slices.
This is usually done with [`.zip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip) in order to iterate in lockstep.
Note that, for convenience, the function [`std::iter::zip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.zip.html) does the same and avoids explicitly writing `.iter()` (it's done internally).

If only the whole diagnostic is required, then [`.all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) can be used on `.zip()`.
On the other hand, if each matching pair has to be considered, then [`.filter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) will provide only these pairs to the usual `for` loop (then starting from here you do whatever you want with this pair).

```rust
fn equiv_whole_slices(
    a: &[(usize, &str)],
    b: &[(usize, &str)],
) {
    // let equiv = a.len() == b.len()
    //     && a.iter()
    //         .zip(b.iter())
    //         .all(|((a_i, _a_s), (b_i, _b_s))| a_i == b_i);
    let equiv = a.len() == b.len()
        && std::iter::zip(a, b).all(|((a_i, _a_s), (b_i, _b_s))| a_i == b_i);
    println!("comparing {:?}", a);
    println!("  against {:?}", b);
    println!("      ~~> {:?}", equiv);
}

fn each_equiv_elements(
    a: &[(usize, &str)],
    b: &[(usize, &str)],
) {
    println!("iterating over {:?}", a);
    println!("           and {:?}", b);
    // for (ta, tb) in a
    //     .iter()
    //     .zip(b.iter())
    //     .filter(|((a_i, _a_s), (b_i, _b_s))| a_i == b_i)
    for (ta, tb) in
        std::iter::zip(a, b).filter(|((a_i, _a_s), (b_i, _b_s))| a_i == b_i)
{
        println!("• {:?} and {:?}", ta, tb);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let array_1 = [(0, "zero"), (1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three")];
    let array_2 = [(1, "AAA"), (2, "BBB"), (3, "CCC")];
    equiv_whole_slices(&array_1[..3], &array_2);
    equiv_whole_slices(&array_1[1..], &array_2);
    equiv_whole_slices(&array_1[1..3], &array_2);
    each_equiv_elements(&array_1[..3], &array_2);
    each_equiv_elements(&array_1[1..], &array_2);
    each_equiv_elements(&array_1[1..3], &array_2);
}
/*
comparing [(0, "zero"), (1, "one"), (2, "two")]
  against [(1, "AAA"), (2, "BBB"), (3, "CCC")]
      ~~> false
comparing [(1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three")]
  against [(1, "AAA"), (2, "BBB"), (3, "CCC")]
      ~~> true
comparing [(1, "one"), (2, "two")]
  against [(1, "AAA"), (2, "BBB"), (3, "CCC")]
      ~~> false
iterating over [(0, "zero"), (1, "one"), (2, "two")]
           and [(1, "AAA"), (2, "BBB"), (3, "CCC")]
iterating over [(1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three")]
           and [(1, "AAA"), (2, "BBB"), (3, "CCC")]
• (1, "one") and (1, "AAA")
• (2, "two") and (2, "BBB")
• (3, "three") and (3, "CCC")
iterating over [(1, "one"), (2, "two")]
           and [(1, "AAA"), (2, "BBB"), (3, "CCC")]
• (1, "one") and (1, "AAA")
• (2, "two") and (2, "BBB")
*/
```

Comment: FWIW if you use `std::iter::zip` the formatting is nicer (more consistent), and you don't need to explicitely `.iter()` the slices.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if given slices `x` and `y`, `x[i].0 == y[i].0` for all valid `i`.

One thing that you did not specify is what should happen if those slices have different lengths. I will assume, than they will be not equal in this case, but if you want something different, you can change that.

You can solve this in may ways, I will share one that uses iterators and has a functional flavor to it. Note however that this will probably have the same performance as if you written a for loop yourself.

```rust
pub fn eq(x: &[(usize, &str)], y: &[(usize, &str)]) -> bool {
    if x.len() != y.len() {
        return false;
    }
    
    x.into_iter()
        .zip(y)
        .map(|((x_index, _), (y_index, _))| (x_index, y_index))
        .all(|(x_index, y_index)| x_index == y_index)
}
```

This code turns `x` and `y` into iterators, [zips](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip) them together, [maps](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) away unneeded string slices (this step is not necessary, I have just added it for better readability) and finally checks that for all elements your indexes are equal.